# Find ports not blocked by Proxy Server

Tags: wireless-networking

We are connected with each other with wireless network and there is a proxy server (SQUID perhaps) which makes us connect to Internet.

They have blocked some ports used for gaming, how do I search which ports are not blocked by them? We were able to play counter strike on this wireless LAN, but unable to do so now.

How to search if there are some other ports open we can use to play counter strike?

Comment: We play on LAN, without using internet, i am not sure how this tool can help?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't sure if you meant an internet or LAN game. I assumed internet because you mentioned the proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

You can run [NMap](http://nmap.org/) to see which ports are open on a machine. If you run `nmap localhost` on your machine and then compare with the result of `nmap <your.ip.address>` on the other machine then if there are any differences this will be caused by either machine-local firewall or by router firewall. So if you temporarily turn off the firewall on each machine you will be able to determine exactly what is blocked by the wireless router. This will not automatically give what ports you could use alternatively, but with a little bit of experimenting you should be able to find out.